# Centering a tag on an align environment

Tags: vertical-alignment, align

I want to create a list of two items, labeled (1) and (2), with a `$\star$` tagged to the left, and centered vertically in between the (1) and (2).  If I use the following:

```
\begin{align*}\tag{$\star$}
(1)&stuff here\\
(2)&more stuff here
\end{align*}
```

Then the star is immediately to the left of the (1).  How can I move that star down a bit, so as to seem like the whole list is labeled star, as opposed to just item (1).

I'm open to using `enumerate`/`aligned`/`equation` environments as well if that would be better.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make the inner construction inside an `array`, which boxes it into a single entry:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \tag{$\star$}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}% Spread out array rows
  \begin{array}{c @{\quad} l}
    (1) & \text{stuff here} \\
    (2) & \text{more stuff here}
  \end{array}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Some adjustments, if needed:

- `\quad` is the space between the entries;
- `c l` is the column specification for the left (numbered) and right (textual) columns;
- `\arraystretch` greater than 1 gives a little air between the array rows.

Caveat: `array`'s interior is not set in `\displaystyle`, so you may have to force this explicitly if your construction contains something that is set differently under that style.

---

You would obtain a similar output if you'd used `aligned` (and there's also `alignedat` for multiple alignment points):

```
\begin{equation}
  \tag{$\star$}
  \begin{aligned}
    (1) &\quad \text{stuff here} \\
    (2) &\quad \text{more stuff here}
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: I'd prefer `alignedat` probably. Surely not `array` (it doesn't use `\displaystyle`).

Comment: @egreg: Thanks. Forgot about that. I've added it as a caveat.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative, using `tabstackengine`.  The gap between the items is defined by `\setstacktabulargap{length}`, and the inter-row skip is defined by `\setstackgap{L}{length}`.  In this case, I `\rlap`ed the star, so that it did not affect the centering.  I found the `\hfil` approach easier in this case, because `\centering` redefines `\\`, which concomitantly requires an alternative stacking end-of-line character to be used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\setstacktabulargap{2\tabcolsep}
\setstackgap{L}{1.2\baselineskip}
\begin{document}
\noindent\rlap{($\star$)}
\hfil
\tabularCenterstack{cl}{
(1)& stuff here\\
(2)& more stuff here
}\hfil
\end{document}
```

[image]